# OOP PHP and 'Get-Set'

Tags: php, oop

I'm wondering is there anyway to create 'Get-Set' method only **once** that can be use to every attribute

The following code **is not correct**. Just to make sure you know what I'm looking for

```
class someClass {
    private $attrA;
    private $attrB;
    private $attrC;

    public function get($attr){
        return $this->$attr;
    }

    public function set($attr, $value){
        $this->$attr = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()` in the exact way you describe.

More info on [the official web site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Comment: Oh!! Thanks a lot mate. You save my day : P

Comment: Thanks! You should go back through your asked questions and accept an answer on each, such as this one. Click the check mark below the down arrow. That will help you get more answers on your new questions.

Comment: Thanks again : )

I'm new to this community. So, this comment from you are very useful : )

Comment: Have a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq ; it should tell you everything you need to know. Oh, and your asked questions are at http://stackoverflow.com/users/760363/tar-tw45

Answer (score 0):

Do you want public fields or public properties ?

In case you want properties, where an operation or validation is done when trying to read or trying to modify a property's value, then, I strongly recommend make individual "getter (s)" and individual "setter (s)" for your properties.

It looks difficult at first, but eventually it will make your code extensible and customizable...

Otherwise, just do plain public fields.